# Windows 10 extremely slow, but runs fine on Safe Mode

Tags: windows-10, performance, safe-mode

I have an Acer laptop with windows 10 64 bits. It has an i3 7th CPU, and 4 GB of RAM. It has 800 GB of free space. It two weeks ago, it **suddenly** became **extremely** slow. When I boot into safe mode, it works fine. I tried the clean boot method, and it didn't work. I also tried running avast rescue disk and comodo rescue disk, to check for viruses - and it found nothing.

What can I do?

Thank's

Comment: There are a number of reasons why it would run faster in safe mode. There could be a driver or application (or multiple of these) running on your PC that slows it down that don't get run in safe mode. Also, your PC could just be bogged down from too many background applications running and they aren't run in safe mode, so it seems faster. Odds are your antivirus is slowing it down as well. Windows 10 doesn't need any antivirus other than the built-in Windows defender.

Comment: Windows 10 x64 or x32? Please provide more information about the computer, laptop, desktop, how much diskspace, how much RAM? Are you storing alot of DVD's? Have you defragged your hard disk lately? How about the last time you ran Disk Cleanup? Disk Cleanup in administrative mode, that will also cleanup Windows updates. It could be many factors. Remove unneeded software and all the TEMP folders. CCleaner might help.

Comment: Thank you. I added more data.

Comment: How much memory does the system have? Is this a recent issue, and was it performing normal and this issue started up? Run checkdisk on the drive,

Comment: 4 GB of ram, 800 GB of free space. It started suddenly.

Comment: Do you remember installing any new programs around the time it got very slow?

Comment: How high are your interrupts in Task Manager under Resource Monitor?

Comment: @Aviad Do you have a backup of all your data? By "data", I mean everything that you need to keep, for example school study, university work, any hobby work, and anything else like that?

Comment: First of all, thank's for the fast answers! I didn't install any program in the last months. I'm not sure how to check the interrupts in the Resource Monitor. And I can make a back-up of my data (from safe-mode).

Comment: @Aviad Please press ctrl+shift+enter to bring up Task Manager. If it only shows a few items, click "More details". Next, click the "CPU" column. Does it show anything using more than 5% of the CPU?

Comment: Thank you. But it does not matter anymore. Finally, I formatted the computer.